# Jetty WebSocketClient over ssl

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, jetty

I've got a WebSocket server running in an embedded jetty (8.1.8.v20121106) and would like to connect to it from another Java application with the jetty WebSocketClient. This is the test method I use:

```
@Test
public void testWebSockets() throws Exception {
    logger.debug("START testWebSockets()");
    WebSocketClientFactory factory = new WebSocketClientFactory();
    factory.setBufferSize(4096);
    factory.start();        

    WebSocketClient client = factory.newWebSocketClient();
    client.setMaxIdleTime(30000);
    client.setMaxTextMessageSize(1024);
    client.setProtocol("MyProtocol");                                       

    WebSocket webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
    String wsUrl = "ws://localhost:8080/websocket";
    String wssUrl = "wss://localhost:8443/websocket";
    Future future = client.open(new URI(wssUrl), webSocket);
    WebSocket.Connection connection = (Connection) future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertNotNull("No connection!", connection);
    connection.sendMessage("TestMessage");
    connection.close();
    logger.debug("END testWebSockets()");
}
```

It's not a problem using the wsUrl but I can't get it working with wss. I don't thinks the server is the problem since I have no problem connecting with wss from javascript. What am I doing wrong in this test?

Both the server and the client log a "bad record MAC" on the ssl setup. This is the last part of the server log:

```
    2013-01-15 10:26:06,398 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap OK NEED_TASK consumed=107 produced=0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,399 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@9063ac SSL NEED_TASK i/o/u=75/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1
,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NEED_TASK filled=69/75 flushed=0/0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,413 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@9063ac SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=75/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=
-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NEED_UNWRAP filled=0/75 flushed=0/0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,415 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap OK NEED_UNWRAP consumed=6 produced=0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,416 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@9063ac SSL NEED_UNWRAP i/o/u=69/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=
-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NEED_UNWRAP filled=0/69 flushed=0/0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,419 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap OK NEED_WRAP consumed=69 produced=0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,420 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@9063ac SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,
b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NEED_WRAP filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,421 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] wrap OK NEED_WRAP consumed=0 produced=6
2013-01-15 10:26:06,422 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@9063ac SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,
b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NEED_WRAP filled=0/0 flushed=6/0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,423 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] wrap OK FINISHED consumed=0 produced=69
2013-01-15 10:26:06,424 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@9063ac SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0
,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=69/0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,426 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@9063ac SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0
,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,428 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@9063ac SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=245/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s
=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=245/245 flushed=0/0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,430 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ssl - SCEP@1dac071{l(/127.0.0.1:65084)<->r(/127.0.0.1:8444),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{SslConnection@9063ac SSL NEED_WRAP
i/o/u=245/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1607)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:884)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:758)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.unwrap(SslConnection.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.process(SslConnection.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.access$900(SslConnection.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection$SslEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:666)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1035)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-01-15 10:26:06,463 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - close SCEP@1dac071{l(/127.0.0.1:65084)<->r(/127.0.0.1:8444),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{SslConnection@906
3ac SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=245/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}}
2013-01-15 10:26:06,469 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser -
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1607)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:884)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:758)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.unwrap(SslConnection.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.process(SslConnection.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.access$900(SslConnection.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection$SslEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:666)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1035)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-01-15 10:26:06,506 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0}
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1041)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1607)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:884)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:758)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.unwrap(SslConnection.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.process(SslConnection.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.access$900(SslConnection.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection$SslEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:666)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1035)
        ... 9 more
2013-01-15 10:26:06,470 qtp9902580-23 Selector0 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio - destroyEndPoint SCEP@1dac071{l(null)<->r(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8444),d=true,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1!}-{SslConnection@9063ac
SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=245/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}}
2013-01-15 10:26:06,555 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Disabled read interest while writing response SSL NEED_WRAP i/o/u=245/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0
,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}
2013-01-15 10:26:06,559 qtp9902580-23 Selector0 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection - closed AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0
2013-01-15 10:26:06,560 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio - EOF
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1041)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1607)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:884)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:758)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.unwrap(SslConnection.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.process(SslConnection.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.access$900(SslConnection.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection$SslEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:666)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1035)
        ... 9 more
2013-01-15 10:26:06,623 qtp9902580-25 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint - close SCEP@1dac071{l(null)<->r(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8444),d=true,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1-}-{SslConnection@9063ac SSL
NEED_WRAP i/o/u=245/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {AsyncHttpConnection@17fc2ee,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=0},r=0}}
```

Comment: Your answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154617/how-to-troubleshoot-ssl-bad-record-mac-exception

Comment: @jdelobel - possibly, but unlikely.  he could probably narrow it down by disabling IPv6 in his network adapter and then restart the JVM (among other things).   Also, a Wireshark trace might give you some idea of what kind of traffic is resounding on the network.

Comment: I second the call for a wireshark trace - it would be helpful to see how far the SSL exchange gets. Also, which version of java are you using? If you are using Java 7 I would see if Java 6 made a difference (Java 7 will try to do TLSv1.2 by default...whilst Java 6 will do TLSv1). I bring this up as I recently had problems with Java  7 TLSv1.2 and some mobile clients (Java 6 had no problems).

Comment: I gave up and switched to another client (see my answer below)

Comment: How did you get the server to work?
I am trying to set up a SSL websocket server for javascript but it is not working and on all of the internet you are the only one who mentioned a jetty websocket server working on SSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also tried with Jetty 9.0.3, but got the same exception as  [Jetty - SSL Websocket Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285511/jetty-ssl-websocket-client)

Since it seems that the jetty websocket client has problems where others don't, I switched to the [async http client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), which runs perfect for me:

```
@Test
public void testNingWebSockets() throws Exception {
    logger.debug("START testNingWebSockets()");

    String wsUrl = "ws://localhost:8081/websocket";
    String wssUrl = "wss://localhost:8444/websocket";
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    WebSocketUpgradeHandler handler = new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder().addWebSocketListener(new ClientWebSocket()).build();
    WebSocket websocket = client.prepareGet(wssUrl).execute(handler).get();
    Assert.assertNotNull("No connection!", websocket);
    logger.debug("Connection made: " + websocket.isOpen());
    websocket.sendMessage("TestMessage".getBytes());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    websocket.close();
    logger.debug("END testNingWebSockets()");
}
```

Comment: Switching from Jetty to async+netty also saved my day, thanks. :)

Comment: @snlp and lapo Can you please provide a link to a simple websocket connection implementation of Async Http Client? The one here: https://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/writing-websocket-clients-using-asynchttpclient/   is a little confusing in terms of Listeners.

Comment: See the [async http client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) documentation (the link was broken)