# Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I have a Java application, from which I am trying to connect to a https url but having issues with SSL ending up with the error:

```
Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
(javax.net.ssl.SSLException)
```

Using [SSLPoke](https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029) there is no issue connection to the URL.

For my Java Application some custom values are set for the keystore

```
cat sysprop.properties 
#Mon, 09 Jan 2017 13:43:54 +0000
#bootstrapModulesResource=moduledefinitions.xml
property.folder=../config

ssl.port=8443
jetty.ssl.keystore=../config/keystore
jetty.ssl.keystore.password=xxxx
jetty.ssl.key.password=xxxx
#jetty.ssl.truststore=../config/truststore
#jetty.ssl.truststore.password=xxxx

application.ip.address=127.0.0.1

bootstrapModulesResource=moduledefinitions.xml
```

As SSLPoke is working fine I assume that its not a Java environment issue but more directly an issue with my set up for the application. Could a custom keystore be the cause for the bad record mac error?

This application is running on a production sever and the issue can't be replicated locally (its working fine locally).

How can I go about further debugging this issue?

Comment: Do [any](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39844/getting-ssl-alert-write-fatal-bad-record-mac-during-openssl-handshake) of [these](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1866) other [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154617/how-to-troubleshoot-ssl-bad-record-mac-exception) have similar problems? They're all the same error .. the first link has a good answer (though not sure if it applies to your situation).

Comment: For debugging purposes you should set `javax.net.debug=all` and examine the output for clues. You can edit your question to add the output to it.