# BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe Neo4j and Python using Multi Processing

Tags: python, neo4j, multiprocessing

I am trying to use neo4j using the python driver. Implemented a program that exchanges the data between neo4j and Python frequently and each of the iterations of the program is independent. The program is running perfectly when no parallel processing is used. Then I am trying to implement this using parallel processing in python where I parallelize these independent iterations. I have got a 24 core machine. So I can run quite a few number of processes. Even in parallel execution, the program is executing until the number of processes is 5. For any number greater than this 90% times I am getting the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 828, in close
    self.sync()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 793, in sync
    self.session.sync()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 538, in sync
    detail_count, _ = self._connection.sync()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 526, in sync
    self.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 388, in send
    self._send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 408, in _send
    self.socket.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1015, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 984, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "<ipython-input-4-616f793afd51>", line 9, in func
    d2=run_query(streaming_query)
  File "<ipython-input-2-01a2f4205218>", line 6, in run_query
    result = session.read_transaction(lambda tx: tx.run(streaming_query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 710, in read_transaction
    return self._run_transaction(READ_ACCESS, unit_of_work, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 686, in _run_transaction
    tx.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 835, in close
    self.session.commit_transaction()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 630, in commit_transaction
    self._connection.sync()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 526, in sync
    self.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 388, in send
    self._send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 408, in _send
    self.socket.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1015, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 984, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

BrokenPipeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-da15b33c8ad4> in <module>
      7 pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)
      8 start = time.time()
----> 9 result = pool.map(func, chunks)
     10 end = time.time()
     11 print(end-start)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    288         in a list that is returned.
    289         '''
--> 290         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    291 
    292     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    681             return self._value
    682         else:
--> 683             raise self._value
    684 
    685     def _set(self, i, obj):

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Also, I am receiving the following warnings

```
Failed to read from defunct connection Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687))
Failed to read from defunct connection Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687))
Failed to read from defunct connection Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687))
Failed to read from defunct connection Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687))
Failed to read from defunct connection Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687))
Failed to write data to connection Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687)); ("32; 'Broken pipe'")
Transaction failed and will be retried in 1.1551515321361832s (Failed to write to closed connection Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687)))
```

The server neo4j debug log is as follows

```
2020-04-09 13:07:26.033+0000 INFO [o.n.l.i.StoreLogService] Rotated internal log file
2020-04-09 13:08:16.724+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.t.p.HouseKeeper] Fatal error occurred when handling a client connection: [id: 0xdb5b2521, L:/127.0.0.1:7687 ! R:/127.0.0.1:58086] javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:472)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:799)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:433)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:330)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1709)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:970)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:295)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1301)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1203)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1247)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: bad record MAC
    at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.decrypt(EngineInputRecord.java:238)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:963)
    ... 26 more
```

Few points I would like to mention

- Tried to use a single driver for the whole program and setting up session as and when required
- I tried to use a driver for each process and I am still facing the issue.
- This sounds odd but I tried to setup a driver as and when a db call is required and closed it immediately after fetching the data. Here I am not facing the broken pipe error but Connection is being refused after hitting the limit.

I want to know what is the ideal way to setup a driver. Also please help me in fixing these issues.

Thanks

Comment: For the time being, handled this with a try-catch block and reinitializing the driver. Solves the issues.

Comment: From the logs it seems that "bad record MAC" in the SSL library is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to troubleshoot SSL "bad record MAC" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154617/how-to-troubleshoot-ssl-bad-record-mac-exception)